# INNER JOIN 3 Data Tables using LINQ

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, postgresql, linq

Trying to use LINQ to join three datatables table1, table2, table3. Table1 and table2 joined on 2 condition and table 1 and table 3 joined on 1 condition. Following is my code. But I am getting an exception saying that 
"Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'."

Below is my code:

```
var result = from cust in tblCust.AsEnumerable()
             join mat in tblMat.AsEnumerable()
             new { coil_id = (string)cust["coil_id"], order_id = (string)cust["order_id"] }
             equals
             new { coil_id = (string)mat["PIECE_ID"], order_id = (string)mat["PRODUCTION_ORDER_ID"] }
                                 join parts in tblParts.AsEnumerable() on (string)mat["PIECE_ID"] equals (string)parts["ProdCoilNo"]
             select new
             {
                 coil_id = mat["PIECE_ID"],
                 order_id = mat["PRODUCTION_ORDER_ID"],
                 part = parts["PartNumber"],
                 gauge = mat["THICKNESS"],
                 width = mat["WIDTH"],
                 weight = mat["WEIGHT"],
                 code = mat["MATERIAL_BLOCK_STATE"],
                 requestor_comment = cust["requestor_comment"],
                 requestor = cust["requestor"],
                 updated_by_comment = cust["updated_by_comment"],
                 updated_by_user = cust["updated_by_user"]                                     
             };
```

I an getting an exception near (string)parts["ProdCoilNo"]

Answer (score 0):

Use the coalesce operator for the field containing null to replace with empty string

Like this:

```
coil_id = mat["PIECE_ID"] ?? String.Empty,
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `coalesce` operator

```
var result = from cust in tblCust.AsEnumerable()
         join mat in tblMat.AsEnumerable()
         new { coil_id = (string)cust["coil_id"], order_id = (string)cust["order_id"] }
         equals
         new { coil_id = (string)mat["PIECE_ID"], order_id = (string)mat["PRODUCTION_ORDER_ID"] }
                             join parts in tblParts.AsEnumerable() on (string)mat["PIECE_ID"] equals (string)parts["ProdCoilNo"]
         select new
         {
             coil_id = mat["PIECE_ID"]?? String.Empty,
             order_id = mat["PRODUCTION_ORDER_ID"]?? String.Empty,
             part = parts["PartNumber"]?? String.Empty,
             gauge = mat["THICKNESS"]?? String.Empty,
             width = mat["WIDTH"]?? String.Empty,
             weight = mat["WEIGHT"]?? String.Empty,
             code = mat["MATERIAL_BLOCK_STATE"]?? String.Empty,
             requestor_comment = cust["requestor_comment"]?? String.Empty,
             requestor = cust["requestor"]?? String.Empty,
             updated_by_comment = cust["updated_by_comment"]?? String.Empty,
             updated_by_user = cust["updated_by_user"]?? String.Empty                                     
         };
```

Comment: Did not help ,.. Same exception